# unable to post to a php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently deploying a contact form to a website via twitter bootstrap where the form posts to a php script that sends an email to an administrator.   The problem is that the form does not submit if the file `js/plugins/validator/jquery.form-validator.min.js` is used for validation

I can get the form to function and submit an email successfully when I remove the validation file below:

```
js/plugins/validator/jquery.form-validator.min.js
```

from the script section at the bottom of the page, but this removes all the validation on the form

```
<form  method="post" action="sendmail.php"  class="input-group input-group-lg" id="subscribeForm"   >
<input type="text class="form-control"  placeholder="Name"   id="name" name="name"  />
<input type="text" name="company" class="form-control" placeholder="company"   /><br />
<input type="text" name="phone"  class="form-control" placeholder="phone"  /><br />
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email" id="sEmail" name="email">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<input type="submit" button class="btn bg-primary">Invite Me!</button>
</span></form><!-- /input-group -->
```

And the content of the sendmail.php

```
<?php
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$company = $_REQUEST['company'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];

$emess = "Name: ".$name."\n";
$emess.= "Company: ".$company."\n";
$emess.= "Email : ".$email."\n";
$emess.= "Phone number: ".$phone."\n";

mail( "send-to-email", "Information Request",
$emess, "From: $email" );
header( "Location: http://www.google.com" );?>
```

Comment: `unable to post to a php script` explain it. you wrote nothing about the problem. `jquery.form-validator.min.js` does not work by itself, it runs only with `$.validate();` and requires `data-validation-` attributes.

Comment: This `<input type="submit" button class="btn bg-primary">Invite Me!</button>` is invalid. It should either be `<input type="submit" button class="btn bg-primary" value="Invite Me!">` or `<button type="submit" button class="btn bg-primary">Invite Me!</button>`

Comment: Plus, make sure you're not outputting before header. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Also as Russell caught the missing quote for `type="text` for your name element, is another reason why your code is failing. A really good catch on Russell's part; *another Eagle eye* amongst us ;)

Comment: Having used [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), would have caught that. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag and for example: 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have

```
<input type="text class="form-control"  placeholder="Name"   id="name" name="name"  />
                 ^ right there
```

which you are missing a quote `"` after text. Throw that in and it should work.

Another thing to note on the php side, use `$name = $_POST['name'];` instead since you are sending a form via post and `$_REQUEST`, by default, contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.

Edit: As Fred pointed out on the input button it should be

```
<input type="submit" class="btn bg-primary" value="Invite Me!" />
```

Comment: Or `<button type="submit" button class="btn bg-primary">Invite Me!</button>` - either will work, since OP had `</button>`.

Comment: Yep! And good edit there as well. Completely forgot to point it out other then stating it was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Changed the input submit tag

```
<form  method="post" action="sendmail.php"  class="input-group input-group-lg" id="subscribeForm"   >
<input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Name"   id="name" name="name"  />
<input type="text" name="company" class="form-control" placeholder="company"   /><br />
<input type="text" name="phone"  class="form-control" placeholder="phone"  /><br />
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email" id="sEmail" name="email">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<input type="submit" value="Invite Me!" />
</span></form>
```

Comment: Err... can you "explain" what you did here including why this would "fix" the problem?

Comment: his submit button is a mix of input and button, this might solve the problem

Comment: No, that shouldn't make a difference. It's not entirely correct but it's not entirely invalid neither. See Russell's answer, he picked up on the missing quote. Plus, you added the quote but did not bother making a note of it.

Comment: yeah I changed that too!